# Blurry scanned documents in pdf

Tags: mac, operating-systems

I have an epson printer/scanner, my os is mac.  My scanned documents are blurry when I scanned them as a pdf, how can I sharpen the image?

Comment: What happens when you scan them as JPEG or other image format? Usually PDF have some configuration for compressing images inside them. Maybe its default is too much compression.

Comment: In jpeg it's fine.

Comment: Maybe this is the problem: http://www.break.com/video/ants-invade-home-scanner-549198

Answer (score 1):

Increase the resolution dpi (dots per inch) in your scan setting. (See third item in the image below.)

The default in mac scanner is 75. Increase it to 300 or 600. The scan will take more time, but it will be much sharper.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since JPEG scan is fine, you have to look for some configuration which allow you change the compression level for image files inside the PDF. Or you could create a PDF from the JPEG image with another tool. One with better control over the PDF creation.